# Error while executing exec('php -v') in php returning garbage (HTTP Response)

Tags: php, linux, exec, shared-hosting

I've a shared server Linux based on which I am facing a weird problem. I am trying to execute by PHP, the following command and it runs ok;  returning me the PHP install path `/usr/bin/php`.

```
exec('which php');// This runs so exec is not disabled
```

but any command i try to execute with `exec('php ...');` fails returning me an array of 98 to 114 elements randomly which almost has garbage all over.  Examples of commands i ran are...

```
exec('php -v');
exec('php -i');
exec('/usr/bin/php -v');
```

None of the above returned something sensible.  Any idea why any command ran by php is not executing?

Below is the `var_dump()` of the data array that `exec()` is returning to me.

**EDIT (After some more RND)**

I was able to execute

```
exec('php -h')
```

and it reuturned me the following array in readable format.

```
string(9) "php -help"
string(47) "Usage: php [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v] [-i] [-f ]"
string(27) "       php  [args...]"
string(36) "  -a               Run interactively"
string(69) "  -b | Bind Path for external FASTCGI Server mode"
string(57) "  -C               Do not chdir to the script's directory"
string(58) "  -c | Look for php.ini file in this directory"
string(47) "  -n               No php.ini file will be used"
string(56) "  -d foo[=bar]     Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'"
string(70) "  -e               Generate extended information for debugger/profiler"
string(46) "  -f         Parse .  Implies `-q'"
string(28) "  -h               This help"
string(34) "  -i               PHP information"
string(43) "  -l               Syntax check only (lint)"
string(43) "  -m               Show compiled in modules"
string(60) "  -q               Quiet-mode.  Suppress HTTP Header output."
string(60) "  -s               Display colour syntax highlighted source."
string(33) "  -v               Version number"
string(72) "  -w               Display source with stripped comments and whitespace."
string(46) "  -z         Load Zend extension ."
string(75) "  -T        Measure execution time of script repeated  times."
This page was created in 0.055487155914307 seconds
```

Oh btw the script i am using to test is the following...

```
<?php
$mtime = microtime(); 
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime); 
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0]; 
$starttime = $mtime; 


if(!empty($_GET['p']) && $_GET['p'] == true){

    //$command = 'php -help'; //this works
    //$command = 'cat ' . getcwd() . '/dummy1.txt'; //this works echo's a simple text file

    //$command = 'php -q ' . getcwd() . '/dummy1.txt'; //NOT WORKING
    $command = 'php -m'; //NOT WORKING

    echo '<div><pre>';
    var_dump($command);
    echo '</pre></div>';

    exec($command, $output, $return);
    //passthru($command,$output);

    echo '<div><pre>';
    foreach($output as $key => $value){
        var_dump($output[$key]);
    }   
    echo '</pre></div>';
}


$mtime = microtime(); 
$mtime = explode(" ",$mtime); 
$mtime = $mtime[1] + $mtime[0]; 
$endtime = $mtime; 
$totaltime = ($endtime - $starttime); 
echo "This page was created in ".$totaltime." seconds";
?>
```

[Pastebin.org Link](http://pastebin.com/9RG0vLmZ)

[image]

Comment: Let me understand correctly.. You are executing php from... php?

Comment: Don't add screenshot  .. add actual data or put it in pastebin

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs Ya wanted to run independent processes via that way.  Its not possible?

Comment: @Baba added pastebin link :)

Comment: Why don't you use `phpversion()`

Comment: @Sn0opy php version is not what i am checking.  I want to execute an independent process in linux.

Comment: Its just a simple `Content-Encoding` issue in your `/home/nctechim/public_html/iSuite/imcheck/dummy.php` file ....

Comment: @Baba why but cuz in my WAMP environment it outputs perfectly fine result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its PHP CGI which reads script name from the environment thus causing calling script to run multiple or sometimes infinite number of times.

The solution is simply using command php-cli instead of command php.

replaced line `$command = 'php -m';` with `$command = 'php-cli -m';` on your code and everything will work fine.

Comment: Is this `php-cli` some linux only binary?  I can't find it in my WAMP installation

Comment: @LoneWOLFs for WAMP's default configuration in windows 'php -m' will do your job without any problem.

Answer (score 3):

Given that the data appears to be an HTTP response, and you have `Content-Encoding: gzip` in there, I would use [`gzdecode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzdecode.php) on the strings to decode the "garbage".

Comment: that brings up an interesting question: why does `exec('php')` output an HTTP response?

Comment: I guess that it's the output from the script named `dummy.php`. I'm guessing the pastebin contains the results of `var_dump($command, $output)`, so the script seems to echo an HTTP response (2 header fields, a blank line, and then the gzipped content).

Comment: @cbuckley dummy.php file contains just <?php echo "hello world"; ?>.  So what should i do to exactly get just 'Hello World' and not the HTTP Response.  And yes its an output from `var_dump($command,$output)`

Comment: @cbuckley added some new findings can u look into it?

Comment: @LoneWOLFs if that's true, the only thing I can think is [auto_prepend_file / auto_append_file](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.auto-prepend-file).

Comment: @cbuckley adding `ini_set("zlib.output_compression", "Off");` solved the garbage issue but it seems my whole script is running multiple times.  The very script from which I am calling the `exec('php..');` and still seems an HTTP response.

Comment: @cbuckley didn't get the problem solved but seems its the php version issue on server or donno. I'll accept it for pointing out the gzip encoding though :)